# Best pythonic way to template dictionary

Tags: python, templates, dictionary

I have large and complicated settings dictinary, with lists of dictionaries with lists inside, somethings like:

```
settings = {
    'general': {
        'cars': ['car1', 'car2'],
    },
    'local': ['loc1', 'loc2'],
}
```

But any of this settings fields have to be parametrized, because I need many copies of those settings with different values in fields.
Something like:

```
variable0 = 'car'
variable1 = 'loc'
settings = {
    'general': {
        variable0+'s': [variable0+'1', variable0+'2'],
    },
    variable1+'al': [variable1+'1', variable1+'2'],
}
```

So, it is kind of template dictionary. Is there a pythonic way to achieve that?
Right now I found solution, where I import entire python script as variable, and before using it's 'settings' variable, I have to set 'variable0' and 'variable1'.
Is there more clean way to achieve such templating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn it into a function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def get_settings(variable0, variable1):
    return {
        'general': {
            variable0+'s': [variable0+'1', variable0+'2'],
        },
        variable1+'al': [variable1+'1', variable1+'2'],
    }

print get_settings('car', 'loc')
```

Comment: Thank you, finally I used this variant. But those 'settings' will be typed by hands by people, who don't have to know python syntax. That's why I just used file with big dictionary, because it's structure easy to understand.
But those structure still have to be templated. And to give them parse function looks for me not very good, then parse dictionary. Anyway, that's the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

If your dict is also compatible with json:

```
import json
def get_settings(**kw):
    return json.loads(r"""{{
        "general": {{
            "{variable0:}s": ["{variable0:}1", "{variable0:}2"]
        }},
        "{variable1:}al": ["{variable1:}1", "{variable1:}2"]
    }}""".format(**kw)
                      )

print get_settings(variable0="pop", variable1='cheese')
```

Comment: thank you, I'll research if I can use json here :-) Nice idea and solution!